# Where can I find the source code specifically for the minimal debian installer cd?

Tags: debian, virtual-machine, source, gpl

I want to distribute a debian virtual machine as a OVA file, in order to comply with the GPL I want to provide the source code for debian alongside the debian virtual machine.

Instead of downloading all the packages after installation with

```
apt-get source <package-name>
```

I would like to provide the source code for the CD used to install the system and then only download the source code with apt which I had to install after installation.

**Where can I find the source code specifically for the minimal debian installer CD ?**

What I have found so far is the [debian source DVDs](https://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/current/source/iso-dvd/) but that's all packages and not just the packages on the installer CD.